# All non-diagonal entries of $A^2$ and its determinant are both odd

Tags: linear-algebra

Does there exist a symmetric matrix $A$ with integer entries such that all non-diagonal entries of $A^2$ are odd and so is $\text{det}(A^2)$?

I have made no progress on this problem so far and would appreciate a hint. I know that if $A$ is a matrix of odd order with $1$ everywhere except on the diagonal matrices and $0$ on the diagonal matrices, then $A^2$ has all non-diagonal entries as odd. But it does not satisfy the second condition.

Comment: I would suggest just trying some $2\times 2$ matrices, it's not hard to find one that works. Since you're only interested in parity, you can reduce everything modulo $2$, so you only need to look at matrices with $0$s and $1$s as entries.

Comment: Is there a requirement on the dimension ? Because otherwise $A = (1)$ works

Answer (score 2):

For example
$$
A=\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
1& 1\\1& 2
\end{array}
\right), \quad
A^2=\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
2& 3\\3& 5
\end{array}
\right), \quad \det A^2=1.
$$